# Confusion converting a decimal to hex in Swift 5

Tags: swift, numbers, hex

Many versions of this question are posted. My question is slightly different, as I'm getting conflicting results.

If I run the following in a playground, it works fine:

```
let myNumber = 12345
if let myHex = Double(String(myNumber, radix: 16)) {
    print(myHex)
} else {
    print("Bad input as hexadecimal: \(myNumber)")
}
```

This returns 3039.

However, if I change myNumber to 1234, I get the Bad Input message. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, or point me to a similar question? (I have looked)

Comment: What would the expected result be for the input 1234? Why the conversion to Double?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @MartinR. There will be some cases where I think I'll need a double.

Comment: @ICT1901 - Hex representations of numbers are intrinsically tied to the format/type of the number. The hex representations of the integer `100` and of the float `100.0` are completely different. (And, as an aside, we rarely deal directly with hex representation of floating point numbers as there are some many different variables/issues.) If you have a hex string representing an integer, and you want to create a `Double` from that, you have to create an integer from that hex string, and a `Double` from that `Int`.

Answer (score 3):

You are taking a number, `1234`, and converting it to a string (e.g. `4d2`). You're then asking `Double` to try to interpret that alphanumeric hex string, which it obviously cannot do.

If you want the hex string representation, it is simply:

```
let myNumber = 1234
let myHex = String(myNumber, radix: 16)
print(myHex)
```

Your value of `12345` resulted in a hex string that did not happen to contain any `a`-`f` characters (it was `3039`), so the `Double` conversion did not fail. (But it also didn't return the right value, either.)

Comment: Thanks very much Rob.